# Is "a" correct before subsidy in the sentence?

Tags: articles

> The government tried to pacify the protesting framers by announcing
>   **a** subsidy on fertilizers.

I doubt whether **a** should come in **a subsidy** or not? Please clear my doubt.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on context.

If this is the first mention in the article of this particular subsidy, **a** is correct.

If the subsidy has been mentioned earlier (excluding any headlines), then it should be *announcing **the** subsidy*.  The definite article is used only of something the reader or listener is presumed to already be familiar with.

If you're asking whether *any* article should be used, the answer is almost-but-not-quite Yes. The subsidy in question is most likely a specific enactment embracing specific amounts and conditions. Bare *subsidy* would be used only of a general policy or practice; and even in that case the far more common use would be the gerund *subsidizing*, especially if the term has verbal force:

> Agricultural subsidy will be a priority for this Government in the next legislative term.
>   Subsidizing needy farmers will be a priority ...

But, again, even in this case the Government is more likely to cast this as one or more specific acts:

> A subsidy for needy farmers will be a priority ...
>   Agricultural subsidies will be a priority ...